# Hero element with translateZ applied is skewed to the right on Chromium browsers, but not on Firefox. How do I fix it?

Tags: html, css, layout, pug, parallax

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 10px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.hero {
  min-height: 100vh;
  transform: translateZ(-20px) scale(3);
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.hero__text {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #1b1b1b, #1b1b1baa 70%, #0000);
  backdrop-filter: blur(0.1rem);
  color: #ddd;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.hero__image {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.hero__image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.main-section {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
  <section class="hero">
    
    <div class="hero__text">
      <h1>SMK Metland</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, maiores magni distinctio porro placeat facere ut ullam optio neque. Deleniti ipsam dolores quis, ducimus sapiente veniam esse error repellat perspiciatis. </p>

      <button id="daftar">Informasi pendaftaran</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hero__image">
      <img src="https://smkmetland.net/ppdb/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/WhatsApp-Image-2023-01-05-at-14.11.03.jpeg">
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="main-section">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae qui quas aspernatur repellendus ipsam harum deleniti nobis in quod, odit dolores. Nulla eligendi reprehenderit numquam ratione facere sed rerum eos?
    </p>
  </section>
</main>
```

So, I wanted to make a parallax scrolling effect by making the hero section scroll slower. So I applied `perspective` and `transform-style` to the wrapper, also `translateZ` and `scale` to the hero like in the snippet above.

I have been testing it on Firefox, and it works fine, but on Chrome and Edge I found that the **hero appears skewed to the right by a very small amount**.
So what can I do to fix this?

[On Edge, the hero moves a little bit to the right, resulting in a horizontal scrollbar. You can also see a thin white gap on the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyaEr.jpg)

[On Firefox however, the hero behaves as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjZoj.jpg)

I initially tried to add a `translateX` to move the hero to the left, but that messes up the layout on Firefox and mobile browsers. It seems like this problem only persists on desktop Chromium browsers.

Also, I tried to take off the `overflow-y` from the wrapper, and it seems to fix the skewing thing. But it makes the entire thing not scrollable, so not a very useful fix.

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Please make your code into a runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem. Currently there isn’t enough context in the code you have give. You can find the actual HTMLand CSS in your browser devtools inspect facility.? You can find the actual HTMLand CSS in your browser devtools inspect facility.

Comment: I have already added the runnable snippet, please take a look.

Comment: Firefox on my WIndows10 laptop shows the same left hand white margin as Edge/Chrome. However, the caption at the bottom shows differently (fills width on Edge/Chrome, is centered on FF).

Comment: What is your Firefox version? I'm not really sure, but I think this has to do with translateZ's compatibility issue.